# Editar código de sitio web en WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Intento modificar el código fuente de un formulario en mi sitio hecho con WordPress debido a que necesito hacer una conexión entre mi web y otra aplicación. Mi problema es que al editar el código se visualiza por unos instantes las modificaciones pero despues todo el código se restaura.
¿Alguien conoce una solución?

Comment: necesitaríamos saber qué código es el que quieres editar, qué edición quieres hacer, y si hablamos de wordpress en tu propio hosting o wordpress.com

Comment: @amenadiel, es la versión 4.9.6, lo que intento modificar es una vista de mi formulario de la sección contacts, está en la ruta content - remates - cache

Comment: No te sirve editar el caché, éste es sólo una copia temporal del código original y se sobreescribirá contínuamente con éste, máxime si el plugin de caché detecta que no concuerda el código. Debieras editar directamente el plugin que crea el formulario

Comment: Sabes como puedo encontrar la ruta? Es en templates?

Comment: si es un plugin debiera estar en `wp-content/plugins/<nombre-del-plugin>`. Si el formulario es parte del theme, entonces en `wp-content/themes/<nombre-del-theme>` y dependiendo de la estructura de uno u otro puede estar en includes, templates, assets, etc. Busca por un segmento del código que modificas para ver dónde está.